# How many comments just tell users to go elsewhere?

Tags: discussion

I'm wondering how many questions on StackOverflow have comments to the kin of:

> This should go on serverfault.com. - Author

Can someone do a query on this information, like a search for comments containing a link to 'serverfault.com' or 'superuser.com' or 'stackoverflow.com'? Because comments are saved during the migration, they should still be intact.

(Is there even a community dump of data for serverfault/superuser?)

Thanks

Edit: For those who ask, I'm just wondering how often we 'tell' people to go to another site vs just voting to migrate it to the other site.

Comment: The latest data dump has all for sites (including meta, for the first time). Why do you ask, though?

Comment: What is the point? Who cares?

Comment: RE your edit: A query on the comments wouldn't help anything then. You need to make a query versus the close votes. I still don't see how helpful this is or what the purpose is though.

Comment: @Geo And vs reputation of commentors, because perhaps people comment because they don't have enough rep to vote

Comment: @Downvoter: Right, which is why I question what the usefulness of this data would be.

Comment: Troggy and I try to clean up those comments, so your data would be skewed

Answer (score 1):

I leave a comment when I vote to close as to 'why'.

Migration is no different.

People are less likely to read close reasons contained in the `close (1)` link than they are to read them  in comments below the question (where they don't have to click on anything to see the comment).

It also helps that comments are voted on and when you write that something needs to be moved, even people that can't close can vote up your comment, giving it more weight in the eyes of other would-be closers that may be on the fence.

This helps make sure it gets moved quickly because people are checking the close reason to make sure others agree with them.

Comment: I don't see how this answers the question.

Comment: The question's not all that clear... This *might* answer it.